# Which WAR is Netbeans deploying?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, netbeans

**Explanation:**

I currently have a Java Web Project in Netbeans and I'm using Maven. Recently I changed the `pom` in the project in order to generate 2 war files when building: one for development (which I want Netbeans to deploy when selecting "Run Project") and another one for production.

To maintain a certain standard with a previous deployment, I kept the production WAR with the same (default) name of `ReportsPortal.war` and the development version with a `-dev` appended.

**Reference:**

This is the section of my `pom` file that I changed:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>       
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>package-prod</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <configuration>                                       
                            <webResources>                        
                                <resource>                        
                                    <directory>src/main/env/prod</directory>                        
                                </resource>                          
                            </webResources>                    
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>                            
                            <goal>war</goal>                                  
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>package-dev</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <classifier>dev</classifier>                            
                            <webResources>                        
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/env/dev</directory>                        
                                </resource>                          
                            </webResources>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>                            
                            <goal>war</goal>                                  
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>                    
            </plugin>
```

It generates both files (`ReportsPortal.war` and `ReportsPortal-dev.war`). Each one with its environment variables (and different between them).

When right clicking the ReportsPortal project and selecting **Run**, Netbeans starts the Tomcat and the application deployed has the correct values, so I guess it is using `ReportsPortal-dev.war` but I can't be sure.

**My question:**

*How can I know or change the war file Netbeans is using to deploy in Tomcat?*

Answer (score 0):

You should create a separate maven build profile for each of the war files.  You can then invoke the development profile while you are doing your dev work and leave the production profile to be called only when you want to make a release.  This will allow you to control exactly what is getting built.

Comment: Thanks @gwhitake. Although, this doesn't answer my question. I'm following the response here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216657/different-files-to-be-packaged-in-a-maven-war-project) which I consider is a better way than having different profiles. Do you know how to know which war is Netbeans taking to deploy in Tomcat automatically?

Comment: @Chrisitan - This does answer your question. The answer is I don't know, but if you want to be sure... Make a profile (or a classifier). That is the Maven way.

Comment: Yes, I have two classifiers. But can't tell way Netbeans is taking one and not the another.